# How to find the fee recipient address of a validator?

Tags: proof-of-stake, fees

Given a validator public key, is it possible to find the fee recipient address associated with it? (I'm talking about execution layer rewards such as MEV, *not* consensus layer rewards)

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's no association between the two. The validator chooses a fee recipient during a block production, and he can change it between blocks.

The lighthouse [docs](https://lighthouse-book.sigmaprime.io/suggested-fee-recipient.html) explain that the validator is free to chose whatever address he wants, and it's actually the execution node client that sets it:

> During post-merge block production, the Beacon Node (BN) will provide a `suggested_fee_recipient` to the execution node. This is a 20-byte Ethereum address which the execution node might choose to set as the recipient of other fees or rewards.
>
> There is no guarantee that an execution node will use the `suggested_fee_recipient` to collect fees, it may use any address it chooses. It is assumed that an honest execution node will use the `suggested_fee_recipient`, but users should note this trust assumption.