# API to get MEV reward recipient from Beacon Chain

Tags: go-ethereum, beacon-chain, mev

[image: Beacon Chain Website]

Is there any API which I can reliably use to get the MEV reward recipient and block reward for a particular block number as shown on the beacon chain page?

I can use the flashbots relay API but this will only get me details for blocks where the winner uses specific relays and is not comprehensive as a result.

I've tried looking through the beacon chain api (the docs do a poor job of explaining what each api actually returns) to understand and can't seem to find the API I'm looking for.

Comment: Duplicate? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/155048/how-to-find-the-fee-recipient-address-of-a-validator